# Srcset attribute always picks the first definition regardless of screen size

Tags: html, responsive-images, srcset

I've just learned about responsive images, i.e. `srcset` and `sizes` and I'm trying to apply them in a simple example.

I got two images; `foo.webp` that is `463px` wide and `foo@sm.webp` that is `325px`.

Then I implement it like this:

```
<img src="foo.webp" srcset="foo@sm.webp 325w," sizes="(min-width: 768px) 463px">
```

The problem here is that the smallest image is always being used no matter what I set in `sizes`. I want it to just use `foo.webp`.

If I add `foo.webp` to `srcset` as well like so:

```
<img src="foo.webp" srcset="foo@sm.webp 325w," sizes="(min-width: 0) 325px, (min-width: 768px) 463px">
```

Then it will only use `foo.webp` instead of switching to `foo@sm.webp` on mobile...

Is this a DPI issue or something? Or am I just completely misunderstanding how this whole thing works?

Comment: Why not have a look here to learn some of the syntax, usage and understanding of srcset https://css-tricks.com/a-guide-to-the-responsive-images-syntax-in-html/#using-srcset

The page has simple clear explanations with nice examples and also goes from simpler to more complex examples the further you read to help you grasp the basics before moving on.

Comment: I couldn't edit the above comment (5 minute time limit) so adding this here.

DPI is covered in the first example using this syntax to switch between smaller and larger images on high and low res  screens/devices:

`<img 
  alt="A baby smiling with a yellow headband."
  src="baby-lowres.jpg"
  srcset="baby-highres.jpg 2x"
>`

The **2x** part in `srcset` attribute